# When I enter ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email.com" in git it gives "Too many arguments" error

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

When I enter `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email.com"` in git it gives a "Too many arguments" error. How do you solve this issue?

Screenshot[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce. How is this programming-related?

Comment: I don't reproduce your issue on a git-bash or git-cmd in my msysgit windows environment.

Comment: cannt reproduce either. Do you have evil stuff in your mail address?

Comment: @VonC - I'm also on msysgit on Windows 7

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's a typo. You typed `-c` but wanted (and used in your question) `-C`

To use `-c`, the keys have to be already present. Excerpt of [`man ssh-keygen`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen):

> Requests changing the comment in the private and public key files. This operation is only supported for RSA1 keys. The program will prompt for the file containing the private keys, for the passphrase if the key has one, and for the new comment.

Answer (score 39):

I also encountered a "Too many arguments" error using this command, but the cause and solution were a little different.  I copy and pasted the following command (from an Outlook 2010 email) into the command line:

```
ssh-keygen –t rsa
```

and got the error.  A coworker suggested just typing the command instead of copy and pasting it.  I tried that and it worked, so I must have copy and pasted extra characters by accident (maybe some whitespace or null characters).

Comment: thanks I would have never figured that out. seems like some characters are pasted that cannot be seen in the terminal.

Comment: In my case the quotes where wrong:

this: ”
instead of this: "

Comment: A copy / paste issue from confluence + chrome was causing this issue for me as well.

Comment: The attribute -t has an en dash(–) or an em dash(—) instead of a negative sign (-). Change that and voila :)

Comment: Thank you! Copy paste has always a drawback.

Comment: same here! your solution works

Answer (score 2):

For me I was running it in Powershell, the issue was setting the passphrase, I had

```
ssh-keygen.exe -t rsa -b 4096 -N ""
```

But needed

```
ssh-keygen.exe -t rsa -b 4096 -N '""'
```

note: the issue existed with or without -C

I found my fix on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767488/automate-ssh-keygen-t-rsa-so-it-does-not-ask-for-a-passphrase).