# Automate ssh-keygen -t rsa so it does not ask for a passphrase

Tags: ssh-keys

I need to automate `ssh-keygen -t rsa` with out a password i.e. enter at the prompt.
How can I do that from a shell script?

Answer (score 246):

To generate a SSH keypair without being prompted for a passphrase you can do the following:

```
$ ssh-keygen -f id_rsa -t rsa -N ''
```

Comment: Worked for me! Github always asked for a password without the -N option even when not entering a passwort after the promt "Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase)"

Comment: On RHEL 6, I got this error: "`ssh-keygen: option requires an argument -- N`" :(

Comment: OK this was because I used `dzdo` command in front of it, so I had to write: `dzdo -i -u target_user ssh-keygen -f id_rsa -t rsa -N "''"`

Comment: It appears that the space separating the option and the empty passphrase `-N ''` is significant. When I added the space it succeeded!

Answer (score 46):

If you need to do this from PowerShell in windows use:

```
ssh-keygen -f $Name -t rsa -N '""'
```

note you also have to ensure the git bin directory is in your path:

```
$sshPath = "<path>\git\bin\"

$env:path += ";$sshPath"
```

Then to use it in PoshGit it's just:

```
Add-SshKey "<path>\.shh\KeyFilename"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. BTW, `git\usr\bin` is the correct dir.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get an error "Saving key "mykey" failed: passphrase too short (minimum four characters)". I had to switch the double/single quotes, e.g. `ssh-keygen -f $Name -t rsq -N '""'`.

Comment: @AaronJensen same for me. Thanks for the fix. I used `'""'`

Comment: @AaronJensen Thanks! `'""'` is the only variant which worked for me.

Comment: @Daniel-Little I can't find a module PoshGit, the only one I find with this name is posh-git which does not seem to have this cmdlet.  Any more info on it?

Comment: I have searched for this for too long, I had overread this answer. I did not have the idea that Windows PowerShell would be different from other command prompts. This special case must have its own Q/A.

Comment: The first and Second line of this Answer worked for me.
except I had an underscore in my file name
But why does this answer contain \git\bin, what does git have to do with the question/answer.

Comment: if you are parameterising your Powershell Script then...
-f $HOME/.ssh/$keyName\`_$keyType would be used...
`_ required to escape the _

Answer (score 21):

```
$ ssh-keygen -f $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -N ''
```

Comment: This answer is essentially copy and paste from the answer by Shamoon

Comment: @oᴉɹǝɥɔ The answer by Shamoon does not explicitly specify the path to the private key.

Answer (score 13):

Just a correction to answer 2...
I found out on my OL and RHEL system the file name should be id_rsa not id.rsa.

So on a OL or RHEL system the command would be:

```
$ ssh-keygen -f id_rsa -t rsa -N ''
```

Comment: As far as I understood `id_rsa` is the default file name for an RSA key, so if you wants to stick to the default, you are not forced to explicitly use the `-f` option.

Comment: @danidemi while you're right that it's the default, one reason for specifying the `-f` option is so that you can execute this in a script.  You can just reaffirm the default to disable the subsequent prompt.

Answer (score 12):

What about :

```
ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -N ''
```

As noted in `man ssh-keygen` :

```
SYNOPSIS
     ssh-keygen [-q] [-b bits] [-t dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 | rsa | rsa1] [-N new_passphrase] [-C comment] [-f output_keyfile]
(...)
      -q      Silence ssh-keygen.
```

(that is with `openssh-client` package in Debian 9.4 stretch : `OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u4`)

Comment: Worked for me thanks. (OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2)

Comment: `ssh-keygen -q -t ed25519 -f id_ed25519 -N ''` does not work for me,Windows PowerShell in Admin mode on Windows 10 Home. I can only get it to run with `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f id_ed25519`, which will ask me `Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):` twice. How can I avoid having to press any enter button?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ printf '\n' | ssh-keygen -N ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to automate in a bash script the ssh-keygen command and the final answer which works well to me:

```
echo -e "\n" | ssh-keygen -N "" &> /dev/null
```

The echo command with the -e interprets "\n" as an Enter key, but do not work with the passphrase. Then using the option -N "" (empty passphrase) the password will be empty and will not ask for anything.
&> /dev/null will send the 'stdout' and 'stderr' to /dev/null so nothing is printed through the display.

Answer (score 0):

Please Enjoy this script...
Powershell script (e.g. for github)

paste this into your myscript.ps1 file...

```powershell
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$keyName=$(throw "keyName - Param must be supplied"),
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$email=$(throw "email - Param must be supplied"),
    $u="git",
    $d="github.com",
    $c="rsa"
)
$repo="repoName"
$account=":accountName"
$currentDir = Get-Location
Write-Host $HOME/.ssh/$keyName`_$c
mkdir $HOME/.ssh
Set-Location $HOME/.ssh
ssh-keygen -f ./$keyName`_$c -t $c -C $email -N '""'
Add-Content -Path ./config -Value "
Host $keyName
    User $u
    Hostname $d
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile $HOME/.ssh/$keyName`_$c"
Write-Host "`n
Put this key into $d :"
cat $HOME/.ssh/$keyName`_$c.pub
Write-Host "`n
Use this to Clone the $repo repo :
    git clone $u@$keyName$account/$repo.git"
cat config
Set-Location $currentDir
```

above is untested but it is close to what I have working

Command to execute

```console
> myscript.ps1 -keyName yourname -email yourname@yourdomain.com
```