# automate ssh-keygen for github in powershell

Tags: git, powershell, ssh-keygen

Is there a way to automate the `ssh-keygen` method in powershell? I'm trying to do it with the following code, but it requires the user to enter a password.

```
# Create your GitHub SSH Key
$MyEmailAddress = "some.user@github.com"
if (! (Test-Path  ("~/.ssh/id_rsa_test"))){

    ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$MyEmailAddress" -f "id_rsa_test"

}
```

I tried entering the password switch, but then it complains that the password is null.

```
# either
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$MyEmailAddress" -f "id_rsa_test" -N ""

# or 
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$MyEmailAddress" -f "id_rsa_test" -N "$null"
```

I don't want a password in my key.

PS: I'm using [poshgit](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git) which depends on [mysysgit](https://github.com/msysgit/git).

Comment: Please note, the answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14946700/124069) isn't valid since `-N ''` throws a validation error on Windows because -N is `null`.

Comment: the further I dig, the more I'm thinking has to do with [mysysgit](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit) throwing a `null` validation error when maybe it shouldn't. I've posted an "issue" https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/132

Comment: Maybe a I am little off-base, but it does seem a bit important in the creation of a cert that you do use a password - Yes I know and understand each Organization/Business requirements are different. However, when you state that you want to remove the password from the input screen, this could trigger an audit. Just my couple thoughts here. Kent

Comment: Why do you even want to automate ssh-keygen? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Cupcake I'm wiring up a Boxstarter script to automate the deployment and configuration of a Dev computer within a Virtual Machine. When connecting to github, it's a pain to have to enter a password for every push. There are many who just `ENTER` through the `[Type a passphrase]` section. https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Comment: The passphrase for github is not required for my personal repos. My computer has a passphrase, and the VM that this is being deployed on has another passphrase. I'm not worried about anyone committing malitious code to my github repos from my VM.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PowerShell seems to remove the empty double quotes and probably requires to escape them. Using `""""` instead of `""` seems to work. Also, I believe one should use `-P` (passphrase) instead of `-N` (new passphrase in case you change it). So the final command line would be

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$MyEmailAddress" -f "id_rsa_test" -P """"
```

Comment: Same problem `C:\Users\Chase> ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "me@gmail.com" -f "id_rsa_test" -P ""
ssh-keygen.exe": option requires an argument -- P`

Comment: PowerShell seems to remove the empty double quotes and probably requires to escape them. Using `-P """"` seems to work.

Comment: Putting this into a Start-Process cmdlet worked the best for me:

Start-Process ssh-keygen -ArgumentList '-t rsa -b 4096 -P """" -C "name@organization.com" -f "id_rsa"' -Wait

Comment: You could just define it as a variable??? Come on guys: `$password = '""'`.... `-P $password`