# Using Powershell open and pass values to Git Bash

Tags: git, powershell, ssh-keygen

I am creating a powershell script to easily a group of tools include git. I have install git but the problem is I need to open the git bash prompt and pass in a command that will generate SSH keys.

How can I open the git bash prompt and pass the desired values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not protecting your private key with a passphrase, you could use Powershell directly to call ssh-keygen, without having to call the git bash first.

See for instance "[automate ssh-keygen for github in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18677284/6309)":

```
# Create your GitHub SSH Key
$MyEmailAddress = "some.user@github.com"
if (! (Test-Path  ("~/.ssh/id_rsa_test"))){
    ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$MyEmailAddress" -f "id_rsa_test" -P """"

}
```