# Bash Scripting - passing no value

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services

My aim is to create a bash script that can add new users to Ec2 and give access to ssh keys but I am having abit of an issue.

This is my current script and the script stops whenever it requires to generate a private/public key because it asks for the passphrase . How can I configure my script to just press enter?

```
#!/bin/bash

username=$1

ssh-keygen -b 1024 -f $username -t dsa
chmod 600 $username.pub
useradd $username
mkdir /home/$username/.ssh
chmod 700 /home/$username/.ssh
chown ball:ball /home/$username/.ssh
cat ball.pub >> /home/$username/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown 600 /home/.ssh/$username/authorized_keys
chown ball:ball /home/$username/.ssh/authorized_keys

[root@ip-172- /]# ssh-keygen -b 1024 -f ball -t dsa
Generating public/private dsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in ball.
```

Comment: You might want to read about [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) if `$username` contains a space your code will break multiply places

Comment: This appears to be a bit of an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info).  [You can just tell `ssh-keygen` you don't want a paraphrase using the argument `-N ''`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10767488/1695906).  It's usually best to ask about the actual problem rather than your attempted solution.

Comment: Your script is also pretty dangerous -- you should at minimum test whether `$1` was actually passed so you didn't barrel through the process wreaking havoc. Something like `if [[ "$1" == "" ]]; then echo "usage: $0 username" >&2; exit 1; fi;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipe empty lines to `ssh-keygen`:

```
ssh-keygen -b 1024 -f ball -t dsa <<< ''
```

or

```
printf "" | ssh-keygen -b 1024 -f ball -t dsa
```

or reading from `/dev/null`:

```
ssh-keygen -b 1024 -f ball -t dsa < /dev/null
```

Comment: @JoneJamson Running with the `-x` flag might tell you what's wrong: `bash -x my_script.sh`

Comment: Hi , alright could u have a look at this http://pastebin.com/1FBj8T8H . I am stressed out

Comment: @JoneJamson Read my comment about `-x` again.

Comment: could u help me out?

Comment: @JoneJamson See line 31, and afaik see you got an answer for your question, consider asking a new one.